# C# help, I received this during a programming interview

Tags: c#, .net

During a recent interview I was asked to write a program that takes a list of different vehicles, or whatever, that implement a honk interface, use an abstract class, and then have a different honk for the different vehicles.  This is what I came up with so far, and it works fine as long as I call the methods independently.  But when I try to put them into an IEnumerable, and then iterate through, it displays the honk for the abstract class, not the individual classes.  Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace ConsoleHonk
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var myList = GetVehicles();

                //This doesn't display the correct honk
                myList.ForEach(x => x.honk());
            }

            private static List<IHonker> GetVehicles()
            {
                var myList = new List<IHonker>();    

                var myTruck = new Truck();
                var myCar = new Car();
                var myGoose = new Goose();

                myList.Add(myTruck);
                myList.Add(myGoose);
                myList.Add(myCar);

                return myList;
             }
         }

         class Goose : HonkClass
         {
             public virtual void honk()
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Quack");
             }
         }

         class Car : HonkClass
         {

         }

         class Truck:HonkClass
         {
              public virtual void honk()
             {
                  Console.WriteLine("Honk-Honk");
             }
         }

         interface IHonker
         {
              string horn { get; set; }
              void honk();
         }

         public abstract class HonkClass:IHonker
         {
             public void honk()
             {
                  Console.WriteLine("Beep");
             }

             public string horn { get; set; }
         }
    }
```

Comment: You need `virtual` on the `honk()` in the abstract class, and `override` (not `virtual`) on the subclass versions.

Comment: Try to understand *why* those changes need to be made. Read up on the keywords on MSDN (or elsewhere) if you need to.

Comment: There is also a compiler warning telling you that you may be unintentionally hiding `honk()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you need an abstract base class because it's a requirement for your interview. However, generally in this situation, if you do not have that artificial constraint, you should not use a base class at all. You can just have the individual vehicles directly implement the interface.

In general you shouldn't use a base class without good reason. For one thing, C# supports implementing multiple interfaces but does not support multiple inheritance. So you can have a class implement both interfaces `IHonkable` and `ISteerable`, but not inherit from both classes `HonkableBase` and `SteerableBase`.

The problem with your code is that the `Honk` methods aren't overriding the abstract class's, they're *hiding* it. The difference in behaviour is exactly what you describe:

```
public class HidingVehicle : HonkClass
{
    public void Honk()
    {
        Console.Writeline("Hiding honk!");
    }
}

public class OverridingVehicle : HonkClass
{
    public override void Honk()
    {
        Console.Writeline("Overriding honk!");
    }
}

public class HonkClass
{
    public virtual void Honk()
    {
        Console.Writeline("Base honk!");
    }
}
```

Then a method might be:

```
var myHidingVehicle = new HidingVehicle();
var myOverridingVehicle = new OverridingVehicle();
myHidingVehicle.Honk();  //"Hiding honk!"
myOverridingVehicle.Honk(); //"Overriding honk!"

HonkClass hiddenVehicle = myHidingVehicle;
HonkClass overridenVehicle = myOverridingVehcile;
hiddenVehicle.Honk(); //"Base honk!"
overridenVehicle.Honk(); //"Overriding honk!"
```

As you can see from the code, the difference is in the `overriding` keyword.

Hiding can be deliberate, but it's very rarely desirable as it breaks polymorphism. If it you do want to hide, and you're sure there isn't a better option, you can use the `new` keyword in the method declaration to hide the compiler warning and make it clear to anyone reading the code that you're hiding.

Comment: Actually there is a need for an abstract class, the question stated it was part of the requirements. The asker is writing this program as part of an interview and a test of his/her skills.